# jquery addClass and removeClass is not working as I expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some tables separated by div tags. when some one click on a letter I want to view only the relevant div tag contents.  I could do that using this jquery code.

```
$(".expand_button").on("click", function() {
        $(this).next(".expander").addClass('view_expander');
    });
```

but the thing is when the user clicks on another letter it also showing its contents keep showing previously clicked div contents. what I need is if the user clicks on another letter previous things must be hidden. I tried to do it by removing the class "view_expander" but itdidn't work.

```
$(".expand_button").on("click", function() {
            $(this).next(".expander.view_expander").removeClass('view_expander');
        });
```

.

```
 <div class="expand_button"> 
        <h1>A</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="a_section" class="expander">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Ambalanthota
                </td>
                <td>
                    Isuru Morots 
                </td>
                <td>
                    B. G. A. Gamini
                </td>
                <td>
                    0727610675 <br> 0472225200
                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>
                    195/1, D S Senanayake Mw, Ambalanthota
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="expand_button"> 
        <h1>B</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="b_section" class="expander">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Bandarawela
                </td>
                <td>
                    GTS Holding(Pvt)Ltd
                </td>
                <td>
                    CK Bopitiya
                </td>
                <td>
                    0773529044 <br> 0572231231
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    No.38Badulla Road,Bandarwela.
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/fzjev/51/

Comment: yeh! this one is working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you need to remove the class from all others before setting the new one. To be able to still toggle them you need to track if click its the same item again.

```
var selected = null;

$(".expand_button").on("click", function() {

    if (this !== selected) {
        $(".view_expander").removeClass("view_expander");
    }

    $(this).next(".expander").toggleClass('view_expander');
    selected = this;
});
```

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zTN6U/1/

Comment: wow! after your edited reply it is combined both things I was looking for. amazing. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it collapse other content which you click on any expand button.

```
$(".expand_button").on("click", function() {
    $(".expander").removeClass("view_expander");
    $(this).next(".expander").toggleClass('view_expander');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use toggle class or on every click search if there is an element with the class and remove it.
Example:

```
$(".expand_button").on("click", function() {
   var expender = $('.view_expender');
   If (expender.length > 0) {
      $(expender).removeClass('view_expander');
   }
   $(this).next(".expander").toggleClass('view_expander');
});
```

Comment: when using this. this is working totally different. when I click on a letter it is expanding and if I click on another letter it also expanding. when only I again click on a expanded letter then only it is collapsed.